# Analysis Limit- Function Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

A) For every sequence ($p_n$) in $E$ such that $p_n \not= p$ and  $p_n \rightarrow p$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have that
$f(p_n) \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ . ($E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$)

B) $f(x) \rightarrow l $ as $x \rightarrow p$

Prove that $A \Rightarrow B$

---

Proof:

Argue by contradiction.

Suppose $f(x) \rightarrow l$ is not true. Then
$\exists \epsilon_0 > 0$, such that $ \forall \delta  > 0$,—which we choose to be $1/n$ for arbitrary $n$— $\exists x_n \in E$  ,
with $0 < |x_n − p| < 1/n$ but
$|f(x_n) − l| > \epsilon_0$.
Therefore we have found a sequence ($x_n$) which converges to $p$ but $f (x_n)$ does not
tend to $l$. Contradiction.

---

I mostly get this proof on the general level but it's the nitty gritty that troubles me. I have finished first year of a maths degree and I need to get into the habit of digesting every little detail of proofs. I will write in numbered list of questions and I will also try to justify why i think it might be the case. I would appreciate a reponse also in numbered format addressing each point, thanks.

1) Everything up to the second line is fine since it's just negating the definition of tending to a limit.

But why- why choose $\delta$ to be $1/n$?

Why do we have this freedom?

Why $1/n$ specifically?

Is it because we know it's true $ \forall \delta $  and since a sequence is a map from the natural numbers we need a discrete sequence which matches each $x_n$ i.e   $x_1$ to $\frac{1}{1}$ and $x_2$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ etc.
Also because $1/n$ tends to $0$ any decreasing sequence would have sufficed?

2) Why does $x_n$ tend to $p$?
Since $1/n$ tends to $0$ it must be because of **Simple Sandwiching** or **Squeeze Theorem** right? 
So by **Squeeze Theorem** $|x_n-p| \rightarrow 0$ and so $x_n-p \rightarrow 0$ (Easy definition chase)
and so $x_n$ tend to $p$ (Easy definition chase)

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you answered your questions correctly. Since my post (up to here) would not be an answer material, I'll elaborate on $1)$.

We have that $\exists \ \epsilon_0$, such that for any chosen $\delta > 0$, there's an $x$ for which $0 < |x - p| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - l| \ge \epsilon_0$ hold (this is the crude form of the negation). Now we start to play.

Since this holds for any $\delta > 0$, choose $\delta = 1/1$ and call it $\delta_1$. Then, there's some $x$, call it $x_1$, such that $0 < |x_1 - p| < 1/1$ and $|f(x_1) - l| \ge \epsilon_0$. Do the same process, but with $\delta = 1/2$ and call it $\delta_2$, and name the corresponding $x$ as $x_2$.

Continue doing this process. The axiom of choice tells us that we can go on forever doing this, and so obtaining the desired result.

Comment: Note that this only needs the axiom of countable choice, not even dependent choice, not to say the full axiom of choice. Also, note that some amount of choice is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

At its core, the proof is pointing out that sequences are enough to determine limits in the large.

Let's talk about your proof then.  Suppose I didn't know what we were going to do.  As with the first line, you negate the definition and you have that $\exists \epsilon_0 > 0 $ so that, for any $\delta > 0$ there is some $x_{\delta} \in E$ with $|x_{\delta} - p| < \delta$ but $|f(x_n) - l| \ge \epsilon_0$.

The whole "choose $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ " bit is basically just the following.  We want to get a contradiction, so we'd like to contradict 1). So what we'd like to do is construct a sequence $x_n \to p$ for which we get $f(x_n) \not \to l$.

But we pretty much see we can do that at this point, because the above statement just says "no matter how close you get to $p$, you can find a point $x$ so that $f(x)$ is not near $l$".  So we'll choose such a point, say $x_1$ which is close to $p$ but with $f(x_1)$ at least $\epsilon_0$ away from $l$.  Are we done?  No, because maybe if we get closer to $p$ we'll be unable to avoid $l$.  But we know we can pick an even closer point $x_2$ so that this doesn't happen and so on.  The particulars of choosing points $x_n$ so that $0 < |x_n - p| < \frac{1}{n}$ is mostly just a formality.  We just need some sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ with $x_n \to p$ and $|f(x_n) - l| \ge \epsilon_0$.  Which points you pick is entirely up to you.

Why do we know that $x_n \to p$?  Because we're choosing them precisely to satisfy $0 < |x_n - p| < \frac{1}{n}$